# Why do we need Newtonian gravitational field (vector)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, vector-fields

Let's ignore GR(scalar) and I am wondering why do we need to model Newtonian gravitational field using vectors? I can understand electromagnetism because of Lorentz force (right hand rule) but what about gravitational field it just the difference in strength at each point in space! Could there be some problems that can only be solved using vector field for gravity? Maybe I should use temperature (scalar) as a better example to compare Newtonian gravitational field ;D

Comment: Note that in your example, the temperature field corresponds to the Newtonian *scalar potential* field. You can define a "temperature gradient" vector field, which is analogous to the gravitational field.

Comment: @NiharKarve I think it should be pointed out that the analogy is extremely superficial. The temperature can be physically measured, the scalar potential cannot. The only physical aspect of the scalar potential is precisely its gradient, whereas this is not true in the case of temperature. Of course, this is not to disregard the usefulness of the analogy altogether, surely, an analogy is not supposed to be an equivalence.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Absolutely, my point was to say that "scalar" temperature and "vectorial" gravity are actually similar in that you would use the gradient of the temperature field for calculating the heat flow. You could always use the potential in Newtonian gravity, saving the gradient till the very end but, as you say, gravitational potentials aren't really measurable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is force a vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372380/why-is-force-a-vector)

Answer (score 2):

The way gravity comes into the framework of Newtonian mechanics is as a force, i.e., it has a direction from the get-go. So, it has to be a vector. More directly, as mentioned elsewhere, the gravitational field at the North pole and the South pole are roughly of the same magnitude but they are still different vis-à-vis their direction.

Of course, since gravitational force is a conservative force, one can also describe it using a potential formulation where the gravitational potential is simply a scalar which varies from point to point only in its magnitude. However, the physically observable aspect of this scalar gravitational potential is the force that it exerts on a particle. This force would depend on the gradient of the scalar potential, not the value of the scalar potential. This gradient is, of course, a vector, namely, the gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

The force of gravity does not just vary in strength from location to location, but also in direction. A person standing at the South Pole and another person standing at the North Pole (on a boat) experience the same strength of gravity, but the forces are in opposite directions. So, you need vectors to best describe gravity.