# Can we call numbers unidirectional vectors?

Tags: vectors, terminology, mathematics

I have never thought so deeply about addition and subtraction. But today I noticed something. When adding or subtracting numbers, we actually apply the rules we use for vectors (for example, the vectors we use in physics). only it were one size, wouldn't all vectors form a set of real numbers? Or in another way, wouldn't it form the endless set of points that we define as a line in geometry?

For example;

$3-(-1)=4$

If we represent the above subtraction with integers with vectors. We define a $1$-unit vector $\overrightarrow{A}$ going from 0 to the left and a $3$-unit vector $\overrightarrow{B}$ going from 0 to the right.Then we multiply vector $\overrightarrow{A}$ by the scalar $-1$ and add it with vector $\overrightarrow{B}$ . As a result, a one-dimensional $4$-unit vector is formed, going to the right from a point 0 that we defined.

In this case, we use vectors to express some concepts that we define as scalar quantities (for example, temperature). As a result of the measurements we made to say that the temperature of the room has decreased, we see that the temperature of 20 degrees has decreased to 10 degrees. This expression can be defined as 20-10=10. We say that the magnitude of temperature is not a vector concept, but when expressing it, we get help from one-dimensional vectors in temperature changes. Is this true?

Comment: See [Is a 1D vector also a scalar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35562/)

Comment: *only it were one size* What is “it”?

Comment: No, because vector division is not defined, and, therefore, you wouldn't be able to define rational numbers.

Comment: There is an isomorphism between scalars and vectors in a one-dimensional vector space i.e. a one-to-one mapping that preserves vector addition and scalar multiplication. However, they are not the same objects.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to ask for it to be deleted. Duplicates are a good thing! It might happen that someone with the same question poses it in a way similar to what you did, and then finds the original post as a consequence. You shouldn't delete a post just because it is a duplicate. Don't worry =)

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz You are not forced to participate in this site if you don't want to. You can also close your account if you wish. Deleting your questions would also delete their answers. Answers people have put time and effort into to help you.

Comment: Please read the Subscriber Content part of Section 6 of the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing): “You agree that any and all content … that you provide … is perpetually and irrevocably licensed” to the company that operates this site. It is now up to this community to decide whether to allow you to vandalize your own question out of pique, rendering Gorga’s answer nonsense. I think it is unlikely to agree that you can do that. Therefore I have submitted an edit to revert your vandalism.

Comment: Regarding edits by other users that annoy you… that is part of the deliberate design of all SE sites. Any user can edit any question or answer to improve it. SE sites are *collaborative* sites and you *don’t* have exclusive control after you post. However, if you delete your account, your posts will no longer be associated with your user name; they will become in effect anonymous.

Comment: Your repeated defacement has been flagged for moderators to decide what to do.

Comment: I sent an e-mail to about what was done to me. I don't want my questions to stop where I am not respected. Apart from that, my questions can be closed or edited, but disrespect is not something I will ever accept.

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz marking a question as a duplicate is not a sign of disrespect

Answer (score 3):

Good morning, what you're saying is interesting. Of course, real numbers are vectors, belonging to $(\mathbb{R},+,*)$, which is an $\mathbf{R}$-vector space. It's a one-dimensional version of the plane. However, its vector nature is "trivial," as you mentioned. You can see it as vectors along a line, but there, all vectors have the same direction.